# Reference variable from string, including . lookups, in Python

Tags: python, global-variables

I've been using the `globals()[name]` method to look up Python variables by name. I can't use only an environment dict, because I need to be able to interface with existing scripts.

The problem is, it doesn't work with `name = "op.eq"`, for example. Other than simply splitting on `.`, looking up `op`, then getting `vars(globals()['op'])['eq']`, is there a way to look up `op.eq` and other dot-notation references?

Comment: This is why you shouldn't use `globals()`. Use a dictionary instead, as recommended in the linked duplicate. You may need to restructure your code entirely.

Comment: Unfortunately, I actually DO need `globals()` - I'm creating an interface to existing Python scripts, and I need to be able to access every global variable defined in those scripts. I have an env dict already, but I need to be able to "fall back" on accessing variables in the global scope if they aren't in the env dict.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Can you please unmark this as duplicate? For the reasons I've outlined, I really do need to use `globals()`, and after looking at the documentation for a while all I can think of is writing my own dot reference resolver which I definitely do not want to do, since it's a core part of the language.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Please either unmark this as duplicate or explain why it's still a duplicate even though my question is not the same as the question it's supposedly a duplicate of.